# JAVA VAADIN7 How to prevent Window closing before certain action, how to let window on top?

Tags: java, window, vaadin7, always-on-top

Project in java, vaadin 7
I have trouble finding a way to prevent my window to be closed before a button inside is clicked. I want the window to stay on top of the other screen content as well.
My code so far :

```
private void handleButtonCancelBatches() {
  if (projectBatchTeller > 0) {
    Button btnYes = new Button("Yes");
    Button btnNo = new Button("No");
    // toDo add click listeners to the buttons 
    HorizontalLayout horizontalLayout = new HorizontalLayout();
    horizontalLayout.addComponents(btnYes, btnNo);
    // toDo add extra informative content to the horizontalLayout
    Window window = new Window( //
       "Cancel "+ projectBatchTeller + " selected batches ?", horizontalLayout);
    window.setWidth(50f, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    window.setHeight(50f, Unit.PERCENTAGE);
    window.setPosition((int) getUI().getWidth() / 2, (int) getUI().getHeight() / 2);
    getUI().getCurrent().addWindow(window);
  } else {
    Notification.show("No batches selected to cancel");
  }
}
// toDo add listeners / handlers for the buttons
```

What I really need is the behavior from a typical Messagebox, but I'm not allowed to add
extra dependencies in the pom nor can I upgrade to a newer version of Vaadin.

If it's not possible, I want to close the window automatically after 60 seconds,
sending a Notifaction informing doing the default path, witch is not processing the batches

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workable solution for it myself. Quite simple actualy, problem
was that I didn't know the word "modal" (I speak dutch)

It gives behavior like a msgbox (like in C# ...)

```
window.setModal(true);
window.setClosable(false);
```